# Libgdx - Serialization Platform Issue

Tags: java, android, serialization, io, libgdx

so lately I have been struggling with Libgdx's serialization tools.  I have currently trying to write both my player class and my GameEntry class onto a file that I can access later when the user quits the application.  My current method works beautifully on the computer version of my app, but when it comes to the android platform, it has not had the same success.  I have added 
to my manifest but I still get the following errors.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error writing file: player.dat (Absolute)
```

And then the following error occurs which crashes the game.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: scores.dat (Absolute)
```

Here is the code for this part of the game.  I call both the save and read methods in the create() method depending on if the platform has detected these files.

```
public static void saveFile(ArrayList<GameEntry> scores) throws IOException{        
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.absolute("scores.dat");
    OutputStream out = null;
    try{
        file.writeBytes((serialize(scores)), false);
    }catch(Exception ex){

    }finally{
        if(out != null) try{out.close();} catch(Exception ex){}
    }

    Gdx.app.log(Asteroids.LOG, "Saving File: " + scores.toString());
}

public static void savePlayer(Player player) throws IOException{        
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.absolute("player.dat");
    PlayerData playerData = new PlayerData(player);
    OutputStream out = null;
    try{
        file.writeBytes((serialize(playerData)), false);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Gdx.app.log(Asteroids.LOG, ex.toString());
    }finally{
        if(out != null) try{out.close();} catch(Exception ex){}
    }

    Gdx.app.log(Asteroids.LOG, "Saving Player");
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static ArrayList<GameEntry> readFile() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.absolute("scores.dat");
    scores = (ArrayList<GameEntry>) deserialize(file.readBytes());

    Gdx.app.log(Asteroids.LOG, "Reading File: " + scores.toString());
    return scores;
}

public static Player readPlayer() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Player player = null;
    PlayerData playerData = null;
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.absolute("player.dat");
    playerData = (PlayerData) deserialize(file.readBytes());

    player = new Player(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Ships/defaultShip.png")), new Vector2((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) - 25, 50), Player.PLAYER_WIDTH,Player.PLAYER_HEIGHT);
    player.setHealth((int) playerData.getPlayerHealth());
    player.setMaxHealth((int) playerData.getPlayerMaxHealth());
    player.setShieldHealth(playerData.getPlayerShieldHealth());
    player.setBulletCount(playerData.getBulletCount());
    player.setShieldRegenRate(playerData.getPlayerShieldRegenRate());
    player.setPlayerScore(playerData.getPlayerScore());
    player.setEntityTexture(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(playerData.getPlayerShipName())));
    player.update();

    Gdx.app.log(Asteroids.LOG, "Reading Player");
    return player;
}

public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
    o.writeObject(obj);
    return b.toByteArray();
}

public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
    return o.readObject();
}
```

Any help or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not want to use absolute (fully-qualified) paths, as the string you would need is different on each platform.  You probably want to use the [`Gdx.files.local()` type path](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Files.html#local%28java.lang.String%29).

See https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/FileHandling for details.  The Libgdx path choices are a bit complicated because the intersection of Java/Android/Desktop/GWT/iOS storage options is complicated.

Comment: When I change the file path to local, the file doesn't seem to be created because when i call the Gdx.files.local(myfile).exists(), it always returns false on android where as on pc it works perfectly fine. I get no errors, but it just recreates the file even if I have already tried to save it in a previous instance

Comment: That's odd.  What does `Gdx.files.local(myfile).getLocalStoragePath()` show?  Also, does the myfile name contain any slashes (directory separators)?  Maybe time for a new/separate question, though.

Comment: I dont seem to have a method called .getlocalstoragepath() when I call Gdx.files.local("player.dat"), for Gdx.files.local.getlocalstoragepath() it does return "data/data/com.me.Asteroids/files/" if that helps

Comment: thank you so much, i did switch to local and edited my implementation and it works now! You have helped with with a problem that has eluded me for two days of stressful debugging.  You sir are a hero

Answer (score 1):

If you are using absolute path than you need to give full path like this

```
FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.absolute("/some_dir/subdir/myfile.txt");
```

You can also refer to this link for any other reference

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/FileModule

Comment: And where would you recommend I save the file if I want to access it in both the pc and android versions?